# iOS 5 lock screen integration: displays currently playing song info including artwork

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to display currently playing song info including artwork in iOS lock screen like Djay for iPad does.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010927